# Alternative for the below update with correlated sub query in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, correlated-subquery

In process of converting the Oracle code to Snowflake, got stuck on the below, any alternate approach for it on the Snowflake side would be appreciated

```
update trgt_tbl T
set (
T.cur_indicator,
T.exp_dt,
T.updt_dt
) =     (
select  'N',
S.exp_dt- 1/86400, 
sysdate
from    src_tbl S
where   S.src_id= T.src_id
and S.ind_updt  = 'U' AND scd_row_num = 1
    )
where   (T.src_id)
in  (
select  distinct X.stc_id
from    src_tbl X
where   X.ind_updt  = 'U' AND scd_row_num = 1
)
and T.cur_indicator = 'Y'
```

### I tried the below two approaches, but not getting expected results.

First approach:

```
update trgt_tbl T
set
cur_indicator = 'N',
exp_dt = DATEADD('SECOND', -1,S.exp_dt),
updt_dt  = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
     
FROM src_tbl S
WHERE S.src_id= T.src_id
AND S.ind_updt  = 'U'
AND scd_row_num = 1
AND T.cur_indicator = 'Y';
```

---

Second approach:

```
update  trgt_tbl T
set T.cur_indicator  =  s.ind,
T.exp_dt = s.dt,
T.updt_dt  = s.ts
from (select    
'N' ind,
DATEADD('SECOND', -1,exp_dt ) dt, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ts,
src_id ,
ind_updt     ,
scd_row_num  
from     src_tbl ) S
where   S.src_id = T.src_id
and S.ind_updt   = 'U' 
and scd_row_num  = 1
and     (T.src_id )
in  (
select  distinct X.src_id 
from    src_tbl X
where   X.ind_updt   = 'U' AND scd_row_num = 1
)
and T.cur_indicator = 'Y';
```

Comment: Hi are you getting an error when you run the update statement or it is not updating the rows ?

Comment: In the first approach try `AND S.scd_row_num = 1`

Comment: Hi, It is updating incorrectly in the below two approaches.

Comment: @DaveWelden, scd_row_num is available only in src_tbl

Comment: The syntax on approach appears to be correct. Are you getting errors or are you simply not getting the expected results? Sample data for the two tables and then for the result following the update may help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @DaveWelden, no errors, but both approaches are not giving the expected results, trying to check if the query can be rewritten using joins

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I refactored it based on my understanding.

And if it's still not working, Please add the sample input and expected output

```
update trgt_tbl T
set 
T.cur_indicator='N',
T.exp_dt=DATEADD('SECOND', -1,S.exp_dt),
T.updt_dt = getdate()
from    src_tbl S
where   S.src_id= T.src_id
and S.ind_updt  = 'U' AND scd_row_num = 1

and   (T.src_id)
in  (
select  distinct X.src_id
from    src_tbl X
where   X.ind_updt  = 'U' AND scd_row_num = 1
)
and T.cur_indicator = 'Y';
```